# Fabric Crashlytics reports not being sent when using crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

When using the delegate method crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution without the handler, crash reports are not being sent. 
From the docs, this method "does not give you the ability to prevent the report from being submitted". However, that's not the case. 
The delegate method is being called though. I'm using it to send logs to a custom server. But if implementing Crashlytics delegate, its report is not sent and does not appear on Fabric's dashboard.

I'm using Fabric 1.7.6 and Crashlytics 3.10.1.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. It'd help if you can share more code and your Fabric init setup so that we can dive in.

Comment: `CrashlyticsKit.delegate = self; [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];` at the end of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: Can you include the full delegate code?